# Change the value of JSON key using JQuery

Tags: ajax, json, jquery

I have some json-code which has multiple objects in it, as such:

```
[
{
    "MNGR_NAME": "Mark",
    "MGR_ID": "M44",
    "EMP_ID": "1849"
},
{
    "PROJ_ID": "88421",
    "PROJ_NAME": "ABC",
    "PROJ_ALLOC_NO": "49"
}
```

]

And my JSON loop snippet is

```
function ServiceSucceeded(res) 
{
 for (index in res) {
    var obj = res[index];
    for (objectIndex in obj) {
        if (objectIndex != "MGR_ID" && objectIndex != "PROJ_ID") {
            alert(objectIndex + ": " + obj[objectIndex]);
        }
    }
 }
}
```

I am already skipping the alert of MGR_ID and PROJ_ID which is not required to display, Could you please help on how to replace/format objectIndex value to proper names? Say MNGR_NAME to Manager Name, PROJ_NAME to Project name ? I am planning to append the formatted value(Proper names) in a div for display.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Store the proper names in a structure, then just decode them when you output them.  For example:

```
displayNames = {
  "MNGR_NAME" : "Manager Name",
  "PROJ_NAME" : "Project Name" //etc...
};

function ServiceSucceeded(res) 
{
 for (index in res) {
    var obj = res[index];
    for (objectIndex in obj) {
        if (objectIndex != "MGR_ID" && objectIndex != "PROJ_ID") {
            alert(displayNames[objectIndex] + ": " + obj[objectIndex]);
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a lookup table:

```
var displayLabels = {  MNGR_NAME: 'Manager Name', PROJ_NAME : 'Project name' };
```

Answer (score 0):

Using http://www.railodeveloper.com/jquery-tojson-function/toJSON.js, you can do this

```
var objData = $.parseJSON(myJSON);     // parse it
objData.jsonIndex = 'some new value';  // change a value
myJSON = $.toJSON(objData);            // resave it
```

I actually use this to solve someone else's problem and [made a jsFiddle for it too](http://jsfiddle.net/mmmshuddup/FfKry/10/).